# docker/git not pulling one specific private repo

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile

I don't think this is a docker problem but that's the only place it shows up.

I've got 3-5 docker projects under my belt wherein I pull private repos from my company's account using the same personal access token in `.composer/auth.json` in the image. It all works so you can assume I (supposedly) know what I'm doing.

I go to do the same thing with a different private repo in this week's project and composer fails with the following error (usernames changed to protect the innocent):

```
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://***:***@github.com/fubar/events.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-fubar-events.git/'

  Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-fubar-events.git'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/fubar/events.git/' not found
```

After checking my code several times, I replaced the `events` repo with another private repo (same username) by merely replacing the URL in `composer.json` and composer runs! I am able to pull several other individual private repos into my container and running composer but not the `events` repo.

I know the `events` repo is pull-able; I did it just last week from the CLI (but that was using SSH keys and not a personal access token).

I poked around the github pages for the pullable and non-pullable repos and can't find anything.

I'm beginning to think it's the name of the repo.

Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then either the repository really doesn't exist, or you lack permissions to access it.  If it's the latter, it could be because the repo requires SSO and your token isn't authorized for that, or the token lacks the proper scopes, or something else.